# How to create a node, and then add it to a link list?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

This is what I have so far! I got confused, because I don't know where to add them. We have been working on nodes in class for sometime, but my professor does not like to explain even when you ask questions. this is our homework assignment. So I would like to know how to create a function to add a node to the link list?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node 
{ 
    double nodeData;
    int nodeLink;
};

void main(void)
{

    struct Node  List[15];
    int Begin, current;

    Begin = 0;

    for (current = Begin; current < 15; current++)
        List[current].nodeLink = 0;

    List[0].nodeData = 3.141593;
    List[0].nodeLink = -1;

    List[1].nodeData = 25.992;
    List[1].nodeLink = -1;

    List[0].nodeLink = 1;

    for (int i = Begin; i != -1; i = List[i].nodeLink)
        printf("%f\n", List[i].nodeData);



}
```

Comment: Why is your `nodeLink` an `int`? It should be referencing the next `Node`

Comment: Regardless of how good or poor your professor is, the proper way to do linked list homework is to draw it on paper first as to how each operation will be done.  Draw boxes, lines, etc.  Don't try and write the program "from your head".  Once you see how it is done on paper, then translating that to code is more or less the easy part.

Comment: Our professor said that nodeLink sould be an int.

Comment: When you used the debugger, what line is causing the issue?

Comment: The code between the `for` loops adds links to the list.  Do you need help with writing a function?  Passing arguments to the function?

Comment: There were no errors! Yes please that would be helpful!

Comment: What is the exact text of the homework assignment ?

Comment: To create a node to add a function to the link list. You should be able to go and take a node from the list stuff data into it and add it to the link list.

Comment: How did your instructor say to pass arrays to functions?  Have you reviewed your text book for how to write a function?

Comment: I recommend setting all your link fields to -2, which represents an empty node.  A link value of 0 is valid and points to the first slot in the array.  A -1 link value represents the end of a list.  When creating a new node, you will have to search the array for an empty slot and empty slots will have a link value of -2.

Comment: He didn't really say I had to learn from the book on how to pass arrays to functions

Comment: @Michael:  The homework assignment is to implement a linked list using an array.  Thus the link fields are indices to the array slot containing the next node.

Comment: Is this C code or C++ code? The tags conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Node.h

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

struct Node {
    double nodeData;
    int nodeLink;
};

extern struct Node *new_Node(double value);
extern void free_Node(struct Node *node);
extern struct Node *next_Node(struct Node *node);
extern void add_to_last_Node(struct Node *list, struct Node *node);

#endif
```

---

Node.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include "Node.h"

#define NUM_OF_NODES 15
#define END_OF_NODE  -1
#define UNUSED       -2

static int initialized = 0;
static int current = 0;
static struct Node Node_pool[NUM_OF_NODES];

static void init(void){
    for(int i=0; i < NUM_OF_NODES; i++){
        Node_pool[i].nodeLink = UNUSED;
    }
    initialized = 1;
}

struct Node *new_Node(double value){
    if(!initialized)
        init();
    if(current < NUM_OF_NODES){
        Node_pool[current].nodeData = value;
        Node_pool[current].nodeLink = END_OF_NODE;
        return &Node_pool[current++];
    } else {
        for(int i=0; i < NUM_OF_NODES; ++i){
            if(Node_pool[i].nodeLink == UNUSED){
                Node_pool[i].nodeData = value;
                Node_pool[i].nodeLink = END_OF_NODE;
                return &Node_pool[i];
            }
        }
        return NULL;
    }
}

void free_Node(struct Node *node){
    node->nodeLink = UNUSED;
}

struct Node *next_Node(struct Node *node){
    return node->nodeLink < 0 ? NULL : Node_pool + node->nodeLink;
}

void add_to_last_Node(struct Node *list, struct Node *node){
    if(!list || !node)
        return ;

    struct Node *temp = list, *prev = NULL;

    while(temp = next_Node(prev = temp))
        ;
    prev->nodeLink = node - Node_pool;
}
```

---

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Node.h"

int main(void){
    struct Node *begin, *aNode, *temp;

    begin = new_Node(3.141593);
    aNode = new_Node(25.992);
    add_to_last_Node(begin, aNode);
    aNode = new_Node(2.2360679);
    add_to_last_Node(begin, aNode);

    for(temp = begin; temp != NULL; temp = next_Node(temp))
        printf("%f\n", temp->nodeData);

    temp = begin;
    while(temp){
        struct Node *save = temp;
        temp = next_Node(temp);
        free_Node(save);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

```
>gcc main.c Node.c -std=c99 -o sample

>sample
3.141593
25.992000
2.236068
```

Answer (score 0):

A linked list is literally that: Its a list of nodes that all point to the next node (by the way, nodeLink should be of type Node*, not int) to form links between one another. A basic one-way linked list would keep track of a head pointer (which is also just a Node*) and use that to recurse down the line (start at head, get the next pointer, then get the next pointer from that, then the next from that...) until you find the position you want to affect or until the next nodeLink is NULL. From there its just creating a new node and assigning the nodeLink values accordingly:

```
Node* newNode = new Node();
newNode->nodeData = 3.14d;
currentNode->nodeLink = newNode;
```

If you *need* it to be an int for some reason, you can use the reinterpret cast:

```
Node* currentNode = reinterpret_cast<Node*>(currentNode->nodeLink); // Grab the next link
currentNode->nodeLink = reinterpret_cast<int>(newNode); // Do the assignment
```

But this will break on systems where sizeof(void*) != sizeof(int) like x86_64 systems, so this is why @Michael in the comments said it *should* be an actual pointer value, not an int. It's also generally bad programming practices to do stuff like this for no good reason.

Comment: Your implementation will not work with an array.  The homework requirement is to implement a linked list using an array.  You can't assume that all linked lists use the heap or pointers.  In an array based linked list, the links are indexes of the array slots containing the nodes.  This technique will also work with files, where the link is the file position (offset).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews He didn't specify that it had to be an array. He provided code that used an array but didn't note that it was a requirement. At least the time I wrote the answer there was no such indication.

Comment: Look at the structure.  The link field is an integer.  Look at the declaration of `list`, it is an **array of structures**.

Comment: Ohh. It makes better sense now!

Comment: But no he said nothing about arrays

Comment: @Darjude Yea, I was responding on basis that it didn't seem to be a requirement. All that was mentioned that the nextNode had be an int. Using an array for a linked list defeats one of the major reasons for using a linked list in the first place anyway: Variable length without having to do any major resizing operations (just tack stuff on!)

Comment: Array based lists are common in constrained environments such as embedded systems or when safety is of concern.  Heap allocation can lead to fragmentation and some platforms cannot be reset or power-cycled to fix the fragmentation issue (think jet airplane flying and needs to reset in mid-flight to fix a fragmentation issue).

Comment: Except Op didn't say that. He wanted help and the only obvious constraint was the next node being an int. I never said anything about it being pointless in all situations. Even the Op said in comments that there is no mention of arrays. So I think the down vote is slightly inappropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible function signature:

```
#define MAXIMUM_NODES 15

void Add_To_List(double value, Node singly_list[MAXIMUM_NODES])
{
}
```

You could call it from your `main` function:

```
  Add_To_List(3.14159, list);
```